# Limit of $\int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x$ without Taylor expansion

Tags: integration, limits

$\def\d{\mathrm{d}}$Consider $$I_n(a) = \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}\,\d x, \quad n\ge 1,\ a \in [0, 1)$$
and evaluate
$$\lim _{n \to \infty} I_n(a). \quad a \in (0, 1)$$

One thing I have found it that

$$\int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}\,\d x = \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\arctan \frac{1}{x}}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}\,\d x$$

Also, I know $$\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x} = \frac{\pi}{2}. \quad \forall x > 0$$

I didn't make it further with that method, so I tried this:

$$\frac{1}{n} \le x \le n,\\
\arctan \frac{1}{n} \le \arctan x \le \arctan n.$$

So I deduced $$I_n(a) \le \frac{\pi}{2} \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\d x}{x^2 + 2at + 1}. \tag{1}$$

The discriminant of the denominator is $4 (a^2 - 1) \le 0\ (\forall a \in [0, 1))$, so $(1)$ becomes

$$I_n(a) \le \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\d x}{(x+a)^2 + \left(\sqrt{\frac{1-a^2}{a}}\right)^2}.$$

I have to get to the answer $$\frac{\pi}{4 \sqrt{1-a^2}} \arctan \frac{\sqrt{1-a^2}}{a}.$$

Comment: from where does this Problem come?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner From a book I prepare from for the university admission.

Comment: have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: @Masacroso I tried, but I still think it should be solved using $\arctan x + \arctan \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$I_n(a) = \frac{\pi}{2} \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{dx}{x^2 + 2at + 1}$$ than $$I_n(a) \le \frac{\pi}{2} \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{dx}{x^2 + 2at + 1}$$

Comment: Is this helpful? $$\int _{\frac{1}{n}}^n \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}dx = \int _{\frac{1}{n}}^1 \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}dx  + \int _{1}^n \frac{\arctan x}{x^2 + 2ax + 1}dx $$

Comment: @JaideepKhare I haven't proved that (and I didn't get the equality)

Comment: Because of $\displaystyle \arctan x+\arctan \frac{1}{x}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ one gets  $\displaystyle I_n(a)=\frac{\pi}{4}\int\limits_{1/n}^n\frac{dx}{x^2+2ax+1}$ . 

And it's $\displaystyle x^2+2ax+1=(1-a^2)(1+(\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}})^2)$ .

Substitution $\displaystyle u:=\frac{x+a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}$ and $\displaystyle \int\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\arctan u + C$ leads to a result with $n$ . Then $n\to\infty$ .

Comment: I know this comment isn't useful but out of curiosity are you studying for the UTCN exam?

Comment: @Lola Yes, I am, how did you know ?

Comment: I'm studying for it too

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are almost there. Since
$$
I_n(a)=\int_{1/n}^n\frac{\arctan x}{x^2+2ax+1}\,dx
=\int_{1/n}^n\frac{\arctan (1/x)}{x^2+2ax+1}\,dx
$$
and
$$
\arctan x+\arctan(1/x)=\frac\pi2
$$
you find that
$$
2I_n=\int_{1/n}^n\frac{\arctan x+\arctan(1/x)}{x^2+2ax+1}\,dx
=\int_{1/n}^n\frac{\pi/2}{x^2+2ax+1}\,dx.
$$
Hence
$$
I_n(a)=\frac\pi4\int_{1/n}^n\frac{1}{x^2+2ax+1}\,dx
=\frac{\pi}{4}\Bigl[\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\arctan\frac{a+x}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\Bigr]_{1/n}^{n}.
$$

Insert the limits, take the limit $n\to+\infty$ and finally use $\arctan x+\arctan(1/x)=\pi/2$ again, and you are done.